# How do I align an image gallery within a div?

Tags: html, css

I am sorry if this is a bit of a n00b question but for the life of me I cannot get this lightbox gallery lined up centrally inside my "content" div.

http://www.justthisdesign.co.uk/bathroom-gallery.html

I am ashamed to be asking such a stupid question but honestly I have tried everything. I have given the last image in each row a class of .last, then played around with padding-right and margin-right but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Don't be ashamed. Everybody starts somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `<div id="content" class="clearfix thumbs" style="text-align: center;">`

Use Margin 4 For all of your Pics in the gallery on the both sides than just Right side!!.You can Remove horizontal padding of content div and adjust the padding area in the width of the div.

Comment: Please ask questions by commenting.

Comment: Sorry but i can't comment on Questions. No Privilege still.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @bmargulies , yeah that's the privilege i was talking about.
anyway, i got the reputation now and can comment now .

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: center;` on `content` div.

Answer (score 1):

give your content div a text-align:center; and give your last images in each row a margin-right of 0 otherwise you will have the extra space on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
     padding: 15px 30px;
     background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

Instead of padding try use margin:

```
#content {
     margin: auto;
     width: 900px;
     background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

And mess around with the width to control its position.
hope this helps.